# test-path, check if file exist

Tags: powershell, shell

i need some help.
I need a powershell script with following actions.

1. The script starts and firts checks whether file 1 is available. If this is available, go to step 2.   If file 1 is not available, the script should end.
2. The script checks whether file 2 exists. If file 2 is available, the script should end; if file 2 is not available, go to step 3.
3. The script checks whether a program X is running. If YES it should exit the program and copy file 3 into a folder. If program X is not running, it should copy file 3 immediately.

Very important! If in step 2 the file 2 exist, the script must quit.

This what i have but even if file 2 is present, it copies the files.

```
$Path = "\\xyz\trigger1.txt"
$Path2 = "$env:userprofile\xyz\trigger2.txt"

if ((Test-Path $Path) -and !(Test-Path $Path2)) {
 
    "trigger1.txt exist"
    "trigger2.txt not exist"

    if((get-process "XXX" -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq $Null)
    { 
        "not Running"
        copy-item "\\xyz\xyz\*" "$env:userprofile\def\" -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        start-sleep -s 5
        Start-Process -filepath "C:\Program Files (x86)\mno\XXX.exe" 
    }
    else
    {
        "running"
        stop-process -name "XXX" -force
        start-sleep -s 5
        copy-item "\\xyz\xyz\*" "$env:userprofile\def\" -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        start-sleep -s 5
        Start-Process -filepath "C:\Program Files (x86)\mno\XXX.exe" 
    }
}
else
{
"trigger1.txt not exist"
start-sleep -s 5
}
```

Comment: You need to enclose that exclamation point in another set of parenthesis. **(!(test-path $file2))**

Comment: life tends to be easier if you avoid unneeded negatives. [*grin*] so instead of testing for "not found", test for "found" and put the negative in the `else` phrase of your `if` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure you're running the script under right user.
- Make sure you use **-PathType Leaf** in Test-Path if you are only looking for files.
- Make sure logical operators are working with parentheses to avoid mistakes.

if ((Test-Path $Path -PathType Leaf) -and (-not (Test-Path $Path2 -PathType Leaf))) {

}

Comment: i tried it, but now, the script jumps directly to trigger1.txt not exist

Comment: Then the first file doesnt exist or the second one does. Make sure the paths are correct and only the first file exists.

Comment: Both files exist. the script must check the two files. If file one exist, go to ckeck if file 2 exist. if exist quit. if not exist copy file from copy-item

Comment: Yes that is exactly what it just did. Both exist so it exited.

Comment: But the script already starts with first file doesnt exist. but definitely it is there. Maybe a brace wrong?

Comment: The script does what you want. It only works if the first file exits and the second file does not. If this condition isn't met, the script exits. Nothing is wrong with it. Unless you want more console information then there's nothing else to do here. It works.